# An alternative to PostgreSQL union?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, select, array, union

In the following example variables in single quotes `''` are arguments passed to the PostgreSQL query. If `'tag_args'` is an empty array, the first row of result table is a row of three nulls and I use result calculated from all the restaurants from the second row. Is there a way of obtaining the same result - calculating three numbers from tagged restaurants or all restaurants, if tags are not given - without duplicating the code with `union all` or otherwise adding a significant amount of lines to the code? I'd be happy to receive any info also on the efficiency of this solution compared to possible other solutions as I'm writing my first project with PostgreSQL and know nothing about the performance side of things.

```
SELECT Total, Total - Drinks AS "Without drinks", Drinks   
FROM (
  SELECT 
  SUM (f.prepared_kgs) 
  FILTER (
    WHERE f.days BETWEEN '2000-1-1' AND '2099-1-1'
    AND f.restaurant_id = ANY (array[1, 3])
  ) AS Total,
  SUM (f.prepared_kgs)
  FILTER (
    WHERE (f.product_id = 10 OR f.product_id = 17) 
    AND f.days BETWEEN '2000-1-1' AND '2099-1-1'
    AND f.restaurant_id = ANY (array[1, 3])
  ) AS Drinks
  FROM food f
  INNER JOIN tags t 
  ON t.restaurant_id = f.restaurant_id 
  WHERE t.name = ANY (array[]::text[])
)
UNION ALL
-- The same query without INNER JOIN and the last WHERE;
```

EDIT: here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KPRb6NeB) with data and the whole query plus SO answer queries.

EDIT 2: here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77727895/11898085) from StackOverflow. The answer is correct if one uses `and` instead of `where` with the `inner join`.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: @mustaccio dbfiddle.uk link added.